# R & Latex: I would like to export the eigen function results as how it is to Latex

Tags: r, latex

I want to export a result from running a simple eigen() function to Latex as how it is in R.

For example

```
a <- c(0,1,0,0,0,0)     
b <- c(1,0,1,1,0,0)     
c <- c(0,1,0,0,0,1)     
d <- c(0,1,0,0,1,1)     
e <- c(0,0,0,1,0,1)     
f <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0)     

A <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)        
eigen(A)
```

The results are shown below:
[image]

At the moment, I uploaded a screenshot onto the latex as an image but I would like to have a Latex table instead so that it's scaled and fitted better into the page.

I don't know how to show such results in Latex. If you have any suggestions, I would really appreciate them.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `eigen.Rnw` containing this text:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

<<eigen1>>=
A <- cbind(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
           c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
           c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
           c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
           c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
           c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0))
e <- eigen(A)
e
@

\lipsum[1][4-6]

<<eigen2>>=
knitr::kable(e$vectors, booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "")
@

\end{document}
```

Install package [`knitr`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=knitr) with `install.packages("knitr")`, then do

```r
knitr::knit2pdf("eigen.Rnw")
```

in R to generate `eigen.tex` and compile `eigen.pdf`. You can open `eigen.pdf` from R with

```r
system(paste(getOption("pdfviewer"), "eigen.pdf"))
```

If you edit `eigen.Rnw` in RStudio, then you can use the `Compile PDF` button, which automates this workflow.

`knitr` syntax and options are documented extensively [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/). There is also package [`kableExtra`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=kableExtra), which extends the options available for formatting matrices and data frames and has documentation [here](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/).